# defining iterative exponentiation and fibonacci procedures

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, iteration

I'm trying to define two functions, `expo-iter` and `fibonacci-iter` that are iterative versions of the exponent function and the fibonacci function. I understand how to do the factorial function (see below), but I don't get these two functions.  For `expo-iter` there were supposed to be two variables (`b` `e`) and for `fibonnaci-iter` there is one variable (`n`).

```
(define factorial (lambda (n) (fact-iter 1 1 n)))

(define fact-iter 
  (lambda (product counter max)
    (if (> counter max) 
        product 
        (fact-iter (* counter product) (+ counter 1) max))))

; (factorial 4)
; (fact-iter 1 1 4)
; (fact-iter 1 2 4)
; (fact-iter 2 3 4)
; (fact-iter 6 4 4)
; (fact-iter 25 5 4)
; (24)
```

Comment: Do you understand how you would compute those mathematical functions iteratively in general (i.e., without worrying about implementing them in Scheme)?  If so, can you add that explanation to your question?  After all, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  Is the primary question here "how do I compute these functions iteratively?" or "I understand how to compute these functions iteratively, but how do I translate this to scheme?"

Comment: Also, please note that the apostrophe `'` should be used in contractions (e.g., Tahmoor's question), but the backquote `\`` is used on Stack Overflow to markup code.  Mixing them can make text hard to read (lots of plain text appears as code).

Comment: The former. I don`t know how to compute these functions iteratively.

Comment: OK, so an answer leading toward those algorithms (since this seems like homework, it's probably better not to give it away), would suffice, and you'd be able to translate those into Scheme?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 1):

### Exponentiation

Exponentiation is probably the easier case here.  First, let's consider the simple *recursive* solution.  *x<sup>n</sup>* is equal to *x(x<sup>n-1</sup>)*, so a simple *recursive* solution is

```
(define (expt x n)
  (if (= n 0)
    1
    (* x (expt x (- n 1)))))
```

Now that's not tail recursive, but you it's *very* similar to the structure of the recursive factorial

```
(define (fact n)
  (if (= n 0)
    1
    (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

and you've already shown that you can convert that to a form that uses tail recursion and an accumulator:

```
(define (fact n)
  (let loop ((n n) (f 1))
    (if (= n 0)
      f
      (loop (- n 1) (* f n)))))
```

In the factorial case, the helper function takes passes the "partial factorial" along with it.  At first it's `n`, then its `n(n-1)`, then `n(n-1)(n-2)`, and so on, until it's finally `n(n-1)...1 = n!`.  For the exponential, your accumulator should be the "partial exponential", first *x*, then *x<sup>2</sup>*, then *x<sup>3</sup>* until it's finally *x<sup>n</sup>*.

### Fibonacci Numbers

Now, the reason that the approaches for factorial and exponential used a single accumulator is that the "partial result" could be captured in just one value.  In the case of the factorial, it was the "partial factorial *n(n-1)...(n-m)*.  In the case of the exponential, it's the *x<sup>m</sup>* (where *m < n*).

To compute the Fibonacci numbers, your partial result that you need in order to compute the next value is really a *pair* of values.  To get the *n<sup>th</sup>* Fibonacci number, you need the *n-1<sup>th</sup>* and the *n-2<sup>th</sup>*.  Regardless of whetheryou consider the first two Fibonacci numbers 0 and 1 or 1 and 1, to compute the third, you only need to consider those two.  To compute the fourth, you only need to remember the third and the second.  To compute the fifth, you only need the fourth and the third.  The iterative algorithm, then, looks something like this:

> a=0          ; *f<sub>i-2</sub>*
>   b=1          ; *f<sub>i-1</sub>*
>   while n > 0
>       b = a + b ; *b is now f<sub>i</sub>*
>       a = b - a ; *a is now f<sub>i-1</sub>, so we can compute f<sub>i+1</sub>*
>       n = n - 1
>   end while
>   return b ; b is now f<sub>n</sub>

If you're comfortable turning the iterative procedure into a tail recursive Scheme procedure, this shouldn't be too difficult.  Just note that you have *two* extra values in the helper function, not just one.