# Iterative version of recursive exponent function

Tags: scheme, racket

I basically need to do a iterative version of the following function which i've already made:

```
(define (expo base e)
  (cond ((or (= base 1) (= e 0)) 1)
        (else (* base (expo base (- e 1))))))
```

im not sure how to so i need help(in racket/scheme))

Comment: possible duplicate of [defining iterative exponentiation and fibonacci procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718128/defining-iterative-exponentiation-and-fibonacci-procedures)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is pass the result around in an accumulator. For that you need an extra parameter, there are several ways to do it, for example using an inner helper procedure:

```
(define (expo base e)
  ; helper procedure
  (define (iter e acc)
          ; now the base case returns the accumulator
    (cond ((or (= base 1) (= e 0)) acc) 
          ; see how the result is accumulated in the parameter
          (else (iter (- e 1) (* base acc)))))
  ; at the beginning, initialize the parameter in the right values
  (iter e 1))
```

Alternatively, we can use a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) for the same effect:

```
(define (expo base e)
  (let iter ((e e) (acc 1))
    (cond ((or (= base 1) (= e 0)) acc)
          (else (iter (- e 1) (* base acc))))))
```

It's good to differentiate between recursive *procedures* and *processes*. Both of the above implementations are recursive *procedures*: syntactically, it's easy to see that they call themselves. But the *processes* they generate are iterative: they're written in a [tail recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) style, so after each recursive call ends there's nothing left to do, and the compiler can optimize away the recursive call and, for all practical purposes, transform it into an iterative loop.

To better understand how iteration works in Scheme read more about this subject in the fantastic [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) book, in the section [Procedures and the Processes They Generate](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2)

Comment: what is acc? i'm not familiar with its purpose

Comment: @user2909199 it's just another parameter to the procedure, used to _acc_ umulate the result. It can have any name, there's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern with converting such recursive functions to iteration is to use an accumulator

```
(define (expo base e)
   (define (go base e accum)
      (if (or (= base 1) (= e 0))
          accum
          (go base (- e 1) (* accum base)))) ; Now this is tail recursion
    ???)
```

Where `???` calls `go` with the appropriate initial value of `accum`. Notice how before the recusive call was inside another call (namely `*`) but now it's the last thing called. This allows for the program to run in constant space.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, a tail recursive algorithm is an iterative algorithm.  However, perhaps you need an explicit iterative algorithm?

```
(define (expo base exp)
  (do ((acc   1 (* acc base))
       (exp exp (- exp 1)))
      ((= 0 exp) acc))))
```

One could add a condition for `(= base 1)` - but, as written, this is a simple as it gets.  Assumes `exp` is an integer.